# Use a rackspace cloud image on Amazon EC2?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, rackspace-cloud

I've a Rackspace (UK) cloud instance, running Ubuntu 11.10, which has taken 10+ man-hours to install all the packages (and custom application code) I need, tighten security, test, etc.

I can take a snapshot of that, and start another instance on Rackspace UK. That worked nicely. Because I've got /etc under git source control I could see the files the start-up process altered were:

- network files (IP address, default gateway)
- root password
- /etc/hostname

About the only post-startup steps I needed to do were a DNS entry and `dpkg-reconfigure postfix` to set the new machine name.

I'm assuming, but haven't tested yet, that I could use this image with Rackspace U.S. But what about with Amazon EC2 (or any other cloud provider for that matter)? Can I just download the image, upload it to Amazon S3, and start new instances with it? If not is there a utility I can run to convert from one linux image format to another?

Comment: It seems Amazon have just launched a special service for this, but only for Windows currently?! http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/  (I cannot say if the Rackspace disk image format is one of the formats they say they support.)

Answer (score 0):

The poor man's approach is to use rsync between servers. Rackspace has a 3-part guide on this, starting here:
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/index.php/Migrating_a_Linux_Server_From_Command_Line_Stage_1